# Derivative of $(2x^2+3)^2(x^3-2x)^4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to know if there's another method in shorter way. I came up to this problem

> Find the $f'(x)$
> $$
> f(x) = (2x^2+3)^2\cdot(x^3-2x)^4
> $$
> Applying product rules
> $$
> \frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x) = f(x)\frac{d}{dx}g'(x) + g'(x)\frac{d}{dx}f(x)
> $$

Solve:

$$ f = (2x^2+3)^2 $$
$$ g = (x^3-2x)^4$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(2x^2+3)^2(x^3+2x)^4 + \frac{d}{dx}(x^3-2x)^4(2x^2+3)^2
$$

$$
2(2x^2+3) 4x(x^3-2x)^4 + 4(x^3-2x)^3(3x^2-2)(2x^2+3)^2
$$

$$
8x(2x^2+3)(x^3-2x)^4 + 4(x^3-2x)^3(3x^2-2)(2x^2+3)^2
$$
$$
8x(2x^2+3)(x^3-2x)^4 + (x^3-2x)^3(12x^2-8)(2x^2+3)^2
$$

Answer:
$$
f'(x) =8x(2x+3)(x^3-2x)^4 + (x^3-2x)^3(12x^2-8)(2x^2+3)^2
$$

Is this correct way or are there other methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At some point your $2x^2+3$ turned into $2x+3$ by mistake; otherwise, you would be able to slightly simplify further by extracting the common factor $(2x^2+3)(x^3-2x)^3$. Having said that, this is a typical "drill"-style problem for practicing the product rule, it is unlikely that an alternative solution exists, or that it is expected from you to do anything else than what you've done.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks my bad, i forgot the $2x^2+3$

Comment: 3@StinkingBishop . In the first half of the 3rd displayed formula of the "Solve", the term $(x^3-2x)^4$ was accidentally replaced with  $(x^3+2x)^4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is correct, and since the question states that you should make use of the product rule, it is the right solution.

If you're new to derivatives, you may not yet have learned about derivatives of logs or about **implicit** differentiation; however you're clearly already familiar with the chain rule, so you should be learning about these other topics very soon.

Once you do, there is a more efficient approach which takes advantage of the properties of logs:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (2x^2+3)^2\cdot(x^3-2x)^4 \\[12pt]
\ln f(x) &= \ln \left[ (2x^2+3)^2\cdot(x^3-2x)^4 \right] \\
&= 2 \ln (2x^2+3) + 4 \ln (x^3-2x) \\[12pt]
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} &= 2 \left( \frac{4x}{2x^2+3} \right) + 4 \left( \frac{3x^2-2}{x^3-2x} \right) \\[12pt]
f'(x) &= f(x) \left[ \frac{8x}{2x^2+3} + \frac{12x^2-8}{x^3-2x} \right] \\
&= 8x (2x^2+3) (x^3-2x)^4 + (12x^2-8) (2x^2+3)^2 (x^3-2x)^3
\end{align}$$

As @RyszardSzwarc notes in the comments below, technically the above method would not work when $x = 0, \pm \sqrt{2}$ as the function value would be zero, but that ultimately does not affect the solution.

Comment: that's great thank you

Comment: There is a slight problem with $x=0$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{2}.$ The formula is correct for $x\neq 0,\pm \sqrt{2}.,$  Then it  can be extended by the continuity.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Good note, thanks, I'll amend the solution.